# Angular 6 - Sorting all table columns works on only two columns instead of all

Tags: angular, sorting, html-table, angular-material, angular6

I'm trying to sort a `MatTable` with `MatSort` of angular material but the problem is I can sort only two columns of my `MatTable` but what I want is to sorting all my columns and I don't understand why it doesn't work... I can click on the arrow like when I want to sort data of my table but nothing happens except with column `multiple` and `occupation` which are sorting well.

Here is my code (I'm well importing `MatSortModule` into my `app.module.ts`):

### csr.component.ts

```
import {AfterViewInit, Component, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {PosteCSRPoste, PosteCSRService} from '../../api';
import {MatSort, MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-csr',
  templateUrl: './csr.component.html',
  styleUrls: [
    './csr.component.css',
    '../app.component.css'
  ]
})
export class CsrComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  displayedColumns = [
    'disciplineCsd',
    'disciplineCsr',
    'multiple',
    'communeIdentique',
    'etablissementCsd',
    'etablissementCsr',
    'occupation'
  ];

  postes = new MatTableDataSource<PosteCSRPoste>();

  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  constructor(private posteCSRService: PosteCSRService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getPostesCSR();
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.postes.sort = this.sort;

  }

  getPostesCSR(): void {
    this.posteCSRService.getPosteCSRCollection().subscribe(data => {
      this.postes.data = data['hydra:member'];
    });
  }
}
```

### csr.component.html

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="postes" matSort class="table table-hover table-bordered mat-elevation-z8">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="disciplineCsd">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header scope="col">Discipline CSD</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let poste">{{ poste.disciplineCsd.nom | capitalize }}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="disciplineCsr">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header scope="col">Discipline CSR</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let poste">{{ poste.disciplineCsr.nom | capitalize }}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="multiple">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header scope="col">Multiple</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let poste">
      <ng-container *ngIf="poste.multiple; else nonMultiple">
        Multiple
      </ng-container>

      <ng-template #nonMultiple>
        Non multiple
      </ng-template>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="communeIdentique">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header scope="col">Même commune</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let poste">
      <ng-container *ngIf="poste.communesIdentiques; else communesDifferentes">
        Mêmes communes
      </ng-container>

      <ng-template #communesDifferentes>
        Communes différentes
      </ng-template>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="etablissementCsd">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header scope="col">Établissement CSD</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let poste">{{ poste.etablissementCsd.nom }}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="etablissementCsr">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header scope="col">Établissement CSR</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let poste">{{ poste.etablissementCsr.nom }}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="occupation">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header scope="col">Occupation</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let poste">
      <ng-container *ngIf="poste.occupation; else vacant">
        Occupé
      </ng-container>

      <ng-template #vacant>
        Vacant
      </ng-template>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50603565/9763687) solve my problem.

The `matColumnDef` property must have the same name as your model